# Error: operand type mismatch for `add'

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I got a problem with this code:

```
.code32
.data
s: .asciz "Hello World!\n"
.text
.global main

main:
        pushl $s
        call printf
        addl $4, $esp

        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
~
```

When I try to compile it with "gcc -g -o file file.s" it shows me this error

Error: operand type mismatch for `add'

Im running a 32-bit linux machine, gcc version 5.4.0. Thanks in advance

Comment: `$esp` is wrong. See if you can spot it.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if you're going to be writing assembly, you're going to need to pay a bit closer attention to detail, or you're going to have a really bad time.

Comment: Yeah, sorry i spot it but now i have, and I dont know why "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: I tried the program on my computer. It works without problems (after replacing the "$esp" by "%esp").

Answer (score 1):

It should be `addl $4, %esp`. The GAS prefix `$` indicates a constant, where `%` is a register.